# Expo-Calendar Permissions

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-calendar

I am trying to use Expo-calendar in my project.

I want to use the `Calendar.createEventAsync(calendarId, details)` which is working fine when it has both Calendar and Reminder permission.

However, my concern is about the Reminder-permission.

I use `Calendar.getDefaultCalendarAsync()` for getting the default calendar-id and then I use `Calendar.createEventAsync()` method to just create an event in Calendar.

I don't want to use Reminder, why do I need reminder permission(for ios)?
Is there any way that I can just ask for Calendar permission for creating an event?

This is the documentation in Expo: [Expo Calendar](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar/#calendarcreateeventasynccalendarid-details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use:

````
 return await Calendar.getCalendarsAsync(Calendar.EntityTypes.EVENT);
}```

and then trying to create an Event:

async function createEvent() {
 try {
   const defaultCalendar = await Calendar.getDefaultCalendarAsync();

   await Calendar.createEventAsync(defaultCalendar.id, {
     title: 'TEST',
     startDate: new Date('2021-01-25'),
     endDate: new Date('2021-01-26'),
   });

   console.log('Event was created.');
 } catch (e) {
   console.log(e.message);
 }
}
````